# Associative definition of ordered pairs?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, reference-request, definition, associativity

There are a few definitions of ordered pairs $(a,b)$.

> Wiener's def: $(a,b)_{W} = \Big\{ \big\{ \{a\}, \emptyset \} \big\}, \big\{ \{b\} \big\} \Big\}$

> Kuratowski's def: $(a,b)_{K} = \big\{ \{a\}, \{a,b\}\big\}$

But neither of these definitions has the associativity property:

> $\big(a,(b,c)\big)=\big((a,b),c\big)$.

Is it possible to define $(a,b)$ such that it still has the defining property

> $(a,b)=(c,d)$ if and only if $a=c$ and $b=d$

as well as the associativity property?

I was just wondering about this question.  My guess is: the answer is no.  But I don't know a method of showing that it is not possible to give such a definition of $(a,b)$.  If you know a reference, please let me know.

Comment: I do not want the ordered triple $(a,b,c)$ to be $((a,b),c)$.  Note the fundamental property of ordered pairs gives us $$\big(a,(b,c)\big)=\big((a,b),c\big)
\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad a=(a,b),\quad (b,c)=c$$

Comment: @GEdgar Oh, this escaped my mind.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If such definition were posible you'll have the following:

By associativity:
$$((a,b),c)=(a,(b,c))$$
but then, by the defining property of the ordered pairs $$(a,b)=a$$
which is absurd since the LHS depends on $b$ and the RHS doesn't.

Comment: Thank you.  I totally forgot about this simple argument.